# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

If you want to run this in the browser, I create a [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2BvoMpQBMxILQ8y2o8zoKxUJDsbzgKyqPrjABCOd+SDwA3xSA1eLgJqxSbItjg5iwWCQiqLWBLVygcCiiItKMKSD8nagBeVXz6jRFxQKYHGAFV67I4JUl2ZwJxuLwYBQEDxuzA8FQm6a7EnlMu09oLl45yWM+OCJOQNOCzxSf2sAXUBmD3Vd6g3YAtx3ECVwPHhtxPRARRUOAr2bM1kwfNxn0Lf83zHd4CGzHwq3YaJDnLSs8xrLA6w1EgDCgZUUOXGADBYGl+AYpjzyMeg4GiaA7A1MYqj4Qd+BHOBl1gQC4Hofs+HfQjrWQW1sAdchKCoF1GGYZpw29KUhUVXx-BlOV4AVKgjCMVCMAwCADnnJtvDMpA7xTPMtGeDIkhkeRoHgZRVHUTRtBsewy1sbQ5FUNUWD0QwTDMSxrCxJxQtcbR8A8bcmiwUJ1lQeJPAGDAhkOWYQmkgUUFK248n2Q48yeGqAEEmMNAAeYqUAAPgagZQUBGrISwBqbylc88QJKAaq-acGqXMUJSlIJQldfSAFkqDAXq6sGvL4yDKVQhtYR7S2j0vUjPoGtw4tAJq4jcziPKhl+EtFxg8AFqnNQHr-J6gN3Fd-u-QG8vIsAXqo96EikAKFGC5wwrcSK7Gi7BMpccK4Di7tpQaLFsdwU8hDtZoJicvxzwIRJpEkOQUeTLL8cx3H0di2R4uJzGya57L3AWUy-ACTa9OeTr8nobrwkiGIkEGuAkiSThoF1ShkG6UxgGQGzbkYyBsAwKRGeRoK2bxjGsSS4x5yF-HCYSkmopip23Fy0W3PFjBJbdZoZZ6hWoliFW1Y1ocBkEXXZkNwwoBN5hzaRyRvBTbcsUdbS4AAXmHLBomILTqAACm9zxKmqQqCG3PTQiIOq8GVABHANlT6UISgMbRWBwPLysqkZ9aQUJCBgBviGbrWNGMGBQj4AAdAwORZFlzHE-u8ruB5Wv9uANgnqem56FAaLnowF8PrY2C2AfReG-5AXH+umFCca2AfquMopWa1FfpPd+cAAByAMoAtywO3YAndQgaCMNgL+eUVranWoAqeu0wB4GuI3GetYqDz3HuwbeosTrBi7nXIBtcLpU2ugZW6Po+iQOgbA7cUBe6QI4IvMhW9v69jwoBdBwCKwkWorPAhV84E2UQSQzwn15w-WXOAIRtcwGQwgeIwhkwvjNDDmXAAlEgn2wMAKg1+mAFRoQ1HTgvhI6+LIjGeBhpYuAIi3q2K0fAmRfDfbmVCEfN+tcc7OjoYZO6nDF6+ICHwDxkib53wfqwfR8QpAZ0uJjbaEABh2QLjQjSiBsndU5mjbK-Uy58BvBgGJWd7DBKoMktOth6Bpk4OEBEo8CbqhgGXPKnh25qHoOPXpng4B2CwIM0Z4yFQCxig1EZcAABuNle6hFDkrOZjiRnKgNFoV+YyJn7OmaTWZizlm1zWbENgeV9GhB0IeC4WAikZRKfjAAPosiA5J+oi3mWk+AhB9l4CWb4Pu+c4D9KgPQDZqRhmeAAIy0gAOL9hqXYWFcAOS0gAKJdPRQAZlpLtKAdhTzqipH0dFTJaRECoAsrAwyUj+VFlXSFPz5mKkzjeMFZcqDRCoFUN2dhMnZOaHWPo7pwQV0PvsrYoRgW9zYPowx7Zinsy0BszwjYy4AEIbyGMruyquZBuDFwNYazwIAMAoFCAyJwGADAcHxAcemEKJkABJ8CutYAyPh5rFQDFCEyX15r1RQCQAUWuAB9SNobw0imDYa-EVg41RsjUm7sEb0WeFYBqq5zKRk3g2Nskw6Z5VYFvgXYt4VmhlpSfmn+9hmjUGJcK-+fQy5VvTPshp9bUXNDFHSgxublRsTDaijZBZTDkDgGXNQUB9XorSSRZoRgIAoFnUxHt8zGbzJHYxBG2apBAA)

I had similar errors before which I was able to fix, but this one just does not seem to want to go away. I am sure it's a typing problem, but no clue on how to go about this.

I looked up similar situations which all advocated you'd properly type the object you're working on, which'd be `task` in my case, which I casted to be of type TaskInterface. I typed the param of replace.key as keyof TaskInterface. Not sure what more I can do.

Can the optional properties in the interface be the cause of it saying typeof never?

interfaces

```js
export interface PopulatableTaskInterface {
  columns?: unknown;
}
export interface TaskBase extends PopulatableTaskInterface {
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  participants?: Array<string>;
  deadline?: Date;
  taskIdentifier?: number;
  messageIds?: Types.Map<string>;
  guildId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  completed?: boolean;
  createdTimestamp?: number;
  completedTimestamp?: number;
  wip?: boolean;
}
export interface TaskBaseInterface extends TaskBase, mongoose.Document {}

export interface TaskInterface extends TaskBaseInterface {
  columns: Types.Array<Schema.Types.ObjectId>;
}
```

Function

```js
async edit(
    query: {
      key: keyof TaskBase;
      value: unknown;
    },
    replace: { key: keyof TaskInterface; value: unknown }
  ): Promise<TaskInterface> {
    const { key, value } = query;
    try {
      const task = (await TaskModel.findOne({ [key]: value })) as TaskInterface;
      if (!task) {
        throwError(
          `Insufficient query: ${query}`,
          Errors.insufficientQuery,
          __dirname,
          __filename
        );
      }
      task[replace.key] = replace.value; // This is where I get the error

      task.markModified(replace.key);
      task.save();
      return task;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: changed replace param to this

```
edit(query:{...}, replace: {key: keyof TaskBase, value: unknown}):
  Promise<TaskInterface> {
    // code here
    task[replace.key] = replace.value; // replaced replace.key for each key key manually
    // by doing `task["taskIdentifier"] = replace.value`, etc.
    // which DID NOT throw an error
}
```

now it's throwing the following error:
`Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unknown` is just like `any`, but inferred its type when type checking. So `unknown` must not be assigned as a value of `TaskInterface`. Then, need to type `value` like following:

```
async function edit<K extends keyof TaskInterface>(
    query: {
      key: keyof TaskBase;
      value: TaskBaseInterface[K];
    },
    replace: { key: keyof TaskBase; value: TaskBaseInterface[K] }
  ): Promise<TaskInterface | void> {
    const { key, value } = query;
   ...
```

It's not necessary to use generics, though I use to make the code easy to read.

Comment: that's brilliant! I wasn't aware you could index an interface with the key.
now that you have pointed that out it does seem rather intuitive.
Helped alot, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Akihito's answer, this could work for you:

```
async function edit<K extends keyof TaskInterface>(
  query: { key: keyof TaskBase; value: unknown; },
  replace: { key: K; value: TaskInterface[K]; }
): Promise<TaskInterface | void> {
  // ...
}
```

This way you would make sure replace object's `key` and `value` refer to the same property, so the error should disappear.

Comment: i did implement something along those lines, thanks!
Now I tried to create a query type/interface as follows: `export type Query<T> = { key: keyof T; value: T[keyof T] };`
But apparently that's not the same as you have above...

Comment: You should do it like this `type Query<T, K extends keyof T> = { key: K; value: T[K] }` so that the key and value both refer to the same property.

Comment: I tried that too, that's where I get this error: `Type 'T[K]' cannot be used to index type 'TaskInterface'.ts(2536)`

Comment: Here's a minimal working example `class Task implements TaskInterface {title: string;}
interface TaskInterface {title: string;}
type Query<T, K extends keyof T> = { key: K; value: T[K] }
async function edit<K extends keyof TaskInterface>(replace: Query<TaskInterface, K>): Promise<TaskInterface | void> {
  const task = (new Task) as TaskInterface; task[replace.key] = replace.value; return task;
}`

Comment: let me try that real quick :p
EDIT: yep sure that works :D. That should defitely yield as a reference to fix my own. Thanks man! Much appreciated. Happy hollydays!